# Find objects not in a relation

Tags: parse-platform

I have a custom object `Team` in Parse with a relation field for the default `User` object. What I would like to do is retrieve all `User` objects which are not related to any `Team` object. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this using the JavaScript SDK? I've been going over the documentation for the [Query object](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html) but I can't find anything.

Perhaps another type of relation, or placing the relation at another place is a better solution. What I want to accomplish is the following: *Each user is allowed to be in one team and one team only.* In addition I need to be able to query the following information from Parse:

- I want to retrieve the `User` objects of all the users assigned to a team
- I want to retrieve the `User` objects of all the users who are not assigned to any team

I have tried using a join table with both the user and team object ids. Then I tried to following query to get all users not assigned to a team:

```
var teammember = Parse.Object.extend('TeamMember'),
    query = new Parse.Query("User");

var innerQuery = new Parse.Query("TeamMember");

query.doesNotMatchQuery('user', innerQuery);
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        response.success(results);
    },
    error  : function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
})
```

But this just gets me the following response: `error: "{"code":102,"message":"bad type for $notInQuery"}"`.

I like the `Relation` type as I can add or remove multiple members at once with a single call to the REST API. I also have no problems retrieving the information on team members when using the `Relation` type to connect the users to the teams. It is just getting the users which are not assigned to any team that is giving me problems.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your objects? Are you having a Team-Object where each "Team" has a reference to one "User"?

Comment: My `Team` Object has a column of the type `Relation` which is typed to the default `User` object. Via this construction each team can have multiple users assigned to it (a pointer would not suffice and an array is limited to 100 members and I don't know if that will be too few in the future).

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but since 'relation' is neither an array nor a pointer, then what is it? Could you paste a screenshot from the relevant part of the Parse dashboard to clarify?

Comment: It is a [Relation](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#manytomany), it is one of the three kinds of relation types in Parse.

Comment: Woops, sorry - I only recalled the other two. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: It seems that the problem could transform into if relation has records or not right?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to construct a query that matches all the users that are part of a relation to a team. If you have this, create a query on PFUser with whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery, with oth keys being the objectID of the PFUsers. Executing this query should give you the correct results. If you use it in BeforeSave or AfterSave, I'd worry about performance though and test it with a large number of datasets.

Comment: I've updated my question, perhaps there is a better solution for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: If it is 1 to 1 relation you should use pointer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need a relation at all. Instead, add a Pointer column to User that points to Team. It ensures that a User can only belong to one team, and your other requirements can be captured as follows.

```js
// All users assigned to a team
query = new Parse.Query('User');
query.exists('team');

// All users assigned to a specific team
query = new Parse.Query('User');
query.equalTo('team', specificTeam);

// All unassigned users
query = new Parse.Query('User');
query.doesNotExist('team');
```

**Update**: If you need to support multiple teams per User in the future, then I would suggest creating a Parse table called Membership with two columns: a Pointer to User and a Pointer to Team. This essentially gives you more control than relying on Parse relations, but it gets a little more complicated.

```js
_ = require('underscore'); // Or lodash

// All users assigned to a team
query = new Parse.Query('Membership');
query.find().then(function (results) {
    // http://underscorejs.org/#uniq
    users = _.uniq(results, false, function (user) { return user.id; });
});

// All users assigned to a specific team
query = new Parse.Query('Membership');
query.equalTo('team', specificTeam);

// All unassigned users
var assignedUsers = []
var unassignedUsers = []
memberQuery = new Parse.Query('Membership');
userQuery = new Parse.Query('User');

memberQuery.find().then(function (memberResults) {
    // http://underscorejs.org/#map
    var ids = _.map(memberResults, function (user) { return user.id; });
    // http://underscore.js.org/#uniq
    assignedUsers = _.uniq(ids);
    userQuery.find();
}).then(function (userResults) {
    var users = _.map(userResults, function (user) { return user.id; });
    // http://underscorejs.org/#difference
    unassignedUsers = _.difference(users, assignedUsers);
});
```

To add and remove Users to/from Teams, you would create Membership objects and save API calls with `Parse.Object.saveAll()` and `Parse.Object.destroyAll()`.

Comment: Thanks, that would certainly work. There are just two concerns I have with this solution:
1) I will have to look for another solution when the customer decides users can be part of multiple teams. This is likely to happen.
2) When I have to add 2 users to a team and remove 3 other users it will only take me 2 requests to the API when using a relation where as this solution will take 5 requests. It is hard to guess how intensely the application will be used which makes me want to make sure I hit the Parse API as few times as possible to avoid problems with the rate limit.

Comment: I updated the answer with an alternative to using relations. Hopefully it addresses #1 and #2 for you.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you for updating your answer, it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This solution at several points depends on "select all from table ABC" operations. Parse is limited to 1000 records max per query, so if any table involved has more than 1000 records this will not work.

Comment: @BillPatterson you are correct, but the fundamental operations remain the same. You have to break things down into tasks based on the query limit and then collect all of the results when you're done. It's tediuous.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into trouble with the answer provided by Seth. When retrieving the users not assigned to a team the difference between the two arrays would be incorrect. I am assuming this is due to the `assignedUsers` having object of type `Membership` and `userResults` being of type `User`. This would make it impossible for underscore to make a proper match.

I would up using this as my Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getTeamlessUsers", function(request, response) {
    var _ = require("underscore"),
        assignedUsers = [],
        companyUsers = [],
        memberQuery = new Parse.Query("TeamMembers"),
        userQuery = new Parse.Query("User"),
        index,
        ubound;

    memberQuery.find().then(function(memberResults) {
        // Make sure each User ID will appear just once
        memberResults = _.unique(memberResults, false, function(item) { return item.get('user').id; });
        // Loop over the unique team members and push the User ID into the array
        for (index = 0, ubound = memberResults.length; index < ubound; index++) {
            var user = memberResults[index].get("user");
            assignedUsers.push(user.id);
        }
        // Get al the users
        return userQuery.find();
    }).then(function(userResults) {
        // Loop over all the users and push the ID into the array 
        for (index = 0, ubound = userResults.length; index < ubound; index++) {
            companyUsers.push(userResults[index].id);
        }
        // Create an array of user IDs which are not present in the assignedUsers array
        var result = _.difference(companyUsers, assignedUsers);
        // Return the IDs of user not assigned to any team
        response.success(result);
    }).fail(function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: For future readers (like me), note that this still has the same issue with "1000 records max" being returned by a query. This will not work if you have more than 1000 records in any table, because your query.find() will not return all the records.  This is my situation, so this solution isn't workable for me.